# Is there a simpler way to calculate Balance type

Tags: polkadot-js

I have two Balance type.

```
const a = registry.createType<Balance>('Balance', 10)
const b = registry.createType<Balance>('Balance', 20)
```

Is there a simpler way to calculate them?  eg (+ - x /)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

Any `Balance` type extends [bn.js (API docs)](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.basics#working-with-numbers) so it has all the [add, sub, etc.](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/)

This means for instance you can do -

```js
const ex = api.consts.balances.existentialDeposit
const val = ex.muln(2).addn(123)

/* transfer 2 x existential + 123 */
await api.tx.balances.transfer("...", val)

/* if you wish to format different only */
const fmt = api.createType("Balance", val).toHuman()
```

You generally don't want to or need to use `createType` the JS API will convert the inputs to the correct formats, e.g where a `Balance` is required in a call, anything of type string, hex, BN, BigInt, number will work and will be converted.

In some cases, e.g. you want to add something and have stuff like `toHuman` in your code (as per the example above), it could be useful to create.

Comment: 'add function' return a BN type.  Is there a simpler way to convert BN type to Balance?

Comment: Why does you need a specific balance type? You don't need this type to it pass anywhere for usage in the API - I guess I tried to convey [this info from the docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.create) above. If you need to create your own, see the last line in the example that does exactly that, BN -> Balance, and then uses the toHuman formatter on the value. Balance is just a BN - it just has some convenience Codec methods.

Comment: hm. thankyou . i just need a type to indicate balance type